# How to subtract from first few data of a large dataset in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a variable `X` having 100 data (`size of X is 1*100, means 1 row and 100 columns`), `X=[9,4,3,2,11,2,3,5,4,22,2,1,5,6,4,32,9,8,4,5,...];` and another variable Y=10, and I want to subtract Y from first 10 values of X. What will be the MATLAB code for it? I am new to MATLAB.
I need answer as `Z=[-1,-6,-7,-8,1,-8,-7,-5,-6,12,2,1,5,6,4,32,9,8,4,5,...]`

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm downvoting this question because what you ask is really basic Matlab. You are expected to do some effort before asking here. Anyway, try the code `Z = X; Z(1:10) = Z(1:10)-10`, which should be self-explanatory. Alternatively, this would also work: `Z = [X(1:10)-10 X(11:end)]`

Comment: The tag [tag:matlab-guide] doesn’t mean “guide me in the use of MATLAB”. Please read the tag guideline for each tag before adding them to your question. Also, please review [ask], it’ll help you get more out of this website.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first 10 elements using `X(1:10)`

Subtract Y: `X(1:10) - Y`

Then combine the rest of the X using `X(11:end)`

```
Z = [X(1:10) - 10, X(11:end)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get some good practice with for loops if you're new

```
for i = 1:10
    y(i) = y(i) - 10;
end
```

Better Practice don't "hardwire" your code.

```
SubValue = 10;
RangValue = 10;

for i = 1:RangValue
    y(i) = y(i) - SubValue;
end
```